# ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character 'f' after object key:value pair

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I´m getting: [Error] invalid character 'f' after object key:value pair  How can I tell what is the (f) that is causing the error? is not quite descriptive the output like in some other languages that tells you the line number at least.

```
{
  "name": "${name}",
  "ulimits": [
    {
      "name": "nofile",
      "hardLimit": 204800,
      "softLimit": 102400
    }
  ],
  "image": "${ecr_url}/${image_name}:${image_tag}",
  "cpu": "${container_cpu}",
  "memory": null,
  "memoryReservation": "${container_memory}",
  "command": [
  "/bin/sh",
  "-c",
  "export DD_AGENT_HOST=$(curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4); /usr/bin/$APPLICATION_ARTIFACTS"
  ],
  "essential": true,
  "mountPoints": [],
  "portMappings": [
    {
      "containerPort": "${container_port}",
      "hostPort": 0,
      "protocol": "tcp"
    }
  ],
  "volumesFrom": [],
  "dockerLabels": {
    "application": "${application}",
    "environment": "${environment}",
    "version": "${image_tag}"
    },
  "logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "${log_driver}",
    "options": "${log_configuration}"
    },
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "AWS_REGION",
      "value": "${task_region}"
    },
    {
      "name": "APPLICATION_ARTIFACTS",
      "value": "${application_artifacts}"
    },
    {
      "name": "ENVIRONMENT",
      "value": "${environment}"
    },
    {
      "name": "VERSION",
      "value": "${image_tag}"
    },
    {
      "name": "SERVER_PORT",
      "value": "${container_port}"
    },
    {
      "name": "DD_TRACE_SAMPLE_RATE",
      "value": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "DD_LOGS_INJECTION",
      "value": "false"
    },
    {
      "name": "DD_ENV",
      "value": "${DD_ENV}"
    },
    {
      "name": "DD_SERVICE",
      "value": "${DD_SERVICE}"
    },
    {
      "name": "TABLE_NAME",
      "value": "${table_name}"
    }
  ]
}
```

I´m getting: [Error] invalid character 'f' after object key:value pair

How can I tell what is the (f) that is causing the error? is not quite descriptive the output like in some other languages that tells you the line number at least.

```
Error: ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character 'f' after object key:value pair

  on deployment/terraform/service-blue.tf line 89, in resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "default_blue":
  89:   container_definitions = local.require_blue_service ? data.aws_s3_object.container_definition_blue[0].body : data.template_file.container_definitions.rendered
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Levinux.

Not sure why the JSON is being flagged as being invalid, since it passes on several online JSON validators.

Comment: **Hi @JimGrant thank you,**

the error was appearing because of the double quotes ( " " ), it was necessary to remove it, because the values of the variables below were numerical and with the double quotes it understood as "512" and the correct one would be only 512


`"cpu": "${container_cpu}",`
`"memoryReservation": "${container_memory}",`
`"containerPort": "${container_port}",`